# mon linux monitor install on centos - can't find glib.h although present

Tags: centos, compiling, libraries

I am trying to install the linux_monitor package under Centos 5.5. When I try make I get:

```
make[3]: Entering directory `/tmp/linux_monitor-2.0RC3/src/server'
if gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I../../src   -I/usr/include/openssl  -g -O2 -Wall -MT linux_mond.o -MD -MP -MF ".deps/linux_mond.Tpo" \
      -c -o linux_mond.o `test -f 'linux_mond.c' || echo './'`linux_mond.c; \
    then mv -f ".deps/linux_mond.Tpo" ".deps/linux_mond.Po"; \
    else rm -f ".deps/linux_mond.Tpo"; exit 1; \
    fi
In file included from linux_mond.c:23:
linux_mond.h:40:18: error: glib.h: No such file or directory
linux_mond.c: In function ‘server’:
linux_mond.c:155: warning: pointer targets in passing argument 3 of ‘accept’ differ in signedness
linux_mond.c: In function ‘client’:
linux_mond.c:334: warning: pointer targets in passing argument 1 of ‘strlen’ differ in signedness
```

I understand it is not finding glib.h, right? I know it is present at /usr/include/glib-1.2/, but I tried several configure flags and looked at the different files and can't find how to let know to configure where that library is.

Comment: I suggest you add a link to the linux_monitor source, if it is publicly available. Does this package not have a configure step?

Comment: Yes, I should have included it: http://sourceforge.net/projects/linux-mon/. And yes, it has a configure step, but I tried passing the path to glib there to no avail:`./configure --libdir=/usr/include/glib-1.2`

Comment: I downloaded and took a look at this project. If it makes you feel any better, it doesn't recognize libglib on my system (Debian squeeze) either. 2.0 seems to be the standard now, but I have 1.2 installed too. If you take a look at the changelog you'll see the last activity on this project took place in Aug 2004. That's nearly 7 years ago. This is clearly a dead project. IF you have a compelling need for this software, I suggest you try and contact the developer directly, before you go any further. Your only other option is to debug the code yourself.

Comment: Many thanks for taking the time to do that. I am going to look for a better option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know it's in `/usr/include/glib-1.2` then you should be able to add `-I/usr/include/glib-1.2` to the 'INCLUDE' definition in your Makefile.  I don't have the package or it's source so I can't be any less vague than that.

EDIT

I just downloaded the package you indicated above. Go to `src/server` and add `-I/usr/include/glib-1.2` to the line `DEFAULT_INCLUDES =-I. -I$(srcdir) -I$(top_builddir)/src`

```
DEFAULT_INCLUDES =-I. -I$(srcdir) -I$(top_builddir)/src -I/usr/include/glib-1.2
```

If you look just below that line you'll see

```
COMPILE = $(CC) $(DEFS) $(DEFAULT_INCLUDES) $(INCLUDES) $(AM_CPPFLAGS) \
          $(CPPFLAGS) $(AM_CFLAGS) $(CFLAGS)
```

which is the line I was referring to in my comment below.

EDIT EDIT

Or more nicely

```
./configure --with-cpp-flags=-I/usr/include/glib-1.2
```

Comment: Thanks. I checked the Makefile, and I found a line that is already including the glib libs with the correct path! So, lost again.

Comment: @AJweb: but that's clearly not getting to gcc because it only says `-I. -I. -I../../src   -I/usr/include/openssl`. Check which macros are being used with  $(CC) .

Comment: @lain, I don't follow you, sorry. How do I do that checking with $(CC) ? The Makefile has this line: `libdir = -I/usr/include/glib-1.2`, which points correctly to the glib directory.

Comment: @AJweb: See my update which may help.